# Databricks Notebook failed with "java.io.FileNotFoundException: Operation failed: "The specified path does not exist.", 404, HEAD"

Tags: pyspark, azure-storage, azure-databricks

I have a notebook which is running daily. Sometime it failed with "Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Operation failed: "The specified path does not exist.", 404, HEAD, [https://adls.dfs.core.windows.net/raw/file.csv?upn=false&action=getStatus&timeout=90"](https://adls.dfs.core.windows.net/raw/file.csv?upn=false&action=getStatus&timeout=90%22). If i re-excute the same notebook, it will complete successfully. I am so clueless about this strange behaviour.

Detailed Error :-

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 458.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 458.0 (TID 2247) (172.18.102.75 executor 1): com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file abfss:REDACTED_LOCAL_PART@adls.dfs.core.windows.net/file.csv. It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved. If Delta cache is stale or the underlying files have been removed, you can invalidate Delta cache manually by restarting the cluster.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.logFileNameAndThrow(FileScanRDD.scala:417)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:369)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:509)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.$anonfun$hasNext$1(FileScanRDD.scala:322)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:317)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:513)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.encodeUnsafeRows(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.$anonfun$processFunc$1(Collector.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:125)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:825)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1658)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:828)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:683)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Operation failed: "The specified path does not exist.", 404, HEAD, https://adls.dfs.core.windows.net/raw/file.csv?upn=false&action=getStatus&timeout=90
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.checkException(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:1344)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.open(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:266)
    at com.databricks.spark.metrics.FileSystemWithMetrics.open(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:336)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.lambda$openFileWithOptions$0(FileSystem.java:4633)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LambdaUtils.eval(LambdaUtils.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.openFileWithOptions(FileSystem.java:4631)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$FSDataInputStreamBuilder.build(FileSystem.java:4768)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.initialize(LineRecordReader.java:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.<init>(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.TextInputCSVDataSource.readFile(CSVDataSource.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat.$anonfun$buildReader$2(CSVFileFormat.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:353)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: Operation failed: "The specified path does not exist.", 404, HEAD, https://adls.dfs.core.windows.net/raw/file.csv?upn=false&action=getStatus&timeout=90
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsRestOperation.execute(AbfsRestOperation.java:246)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsClient.getPathStatus(AbfsClient.java:648)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.openFileForRead(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:694)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.open(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:263)
    ... 43 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2973)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2920)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2914)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2914)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1334)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3123)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3111)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:1096)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJobInternal(SparkContext.scala:2564)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.runSparkJobs(Collector.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.collect(Collector.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.InternalRowFormat$.collect(cachedSparkResults.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.InternalRowFormat$.collect(cachedSparkResults.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.collectResult$1(ResultCacheManager.scala:587)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.$anonfun$computeResult$1(ResultCacheManager.scala:594)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.withFinalPlanUpdate(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:496)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.computeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:594)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.$anonfun$getOrComputeResultInternal$1(ResultCacheManager.scala:542)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResultInternal(ResultCacheManager.scala:541)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:417)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectResult(SparkPlan.scala:413)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectResult(Dataset.scala:3102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectResult$1(Dataset.scala:3093)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3900)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$5(SQLExecution.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:852)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3898)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectResult(Dataset.scala:3092)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.OutputAggregator$.withOutputAggregation0(OutputAggregator.scala:271)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.OutputAggregator$.withOutputAggregation(OutputAggregator.scala:105)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocalBase.generateTableResult(PythonDriverLocalBase.scala:586)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.computeListResultsItem(PythonDriverLocal.scala:620)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocalBase.genListResults(PythonDriverLocalBase.scala:493)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.$anonfun$getResultBufferInternal$1(PythonDriverLocal.scala:675)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.withInterpLock(PythonDriverLocal.scala:556)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.getResultBufferInternal(PythonDriverLocal.scala:635)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.getResultBuffer(DriverLocal.scala:661)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.outputSuccess(PythonDriverLocal.scala:598)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.$anonfun$repl$6(PythonDriverLocal.scala:222)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.withInterpLock(PythonDriverLocal.scala:556)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.repl(PythonDriverLocal.scala:209)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$11(DriverLocal.scala:552)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:215)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContext$.withValue(AttributionContext.scala:95)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:213)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:210)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:50)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:251)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:243)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:50)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:529)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:693)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:685)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:526)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:638)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:431)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:374)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:225)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file abfss:REDACTED_LOCAL_PART@adls.dfs.core.windows.net/file.csv. It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved. If Delta cache is stale or the underlying files have been removed, you can invalidate Delta cache manually by restarting the cluster.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.logFileNameAndThrow(FileScanRDD.scala:417)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:369)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:509)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.$anonfun$hasNext$1(FileScanRDD.scala:322)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:317)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:513)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.encodeUnsafeRows(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.$anonfun$processFunc$1(Collector.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:125)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:825)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1658)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:828)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:683)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Operation failed: "The specified path does not exist.", 404, HEAD, https://adls.dfs.core.windows.net/raw/file.csv?upn=false&action=getStatus&timeout=90
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.checkException(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:1344)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.open(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:266)
    at com.databricks.spark.metrics.FileSystemWithMetrics.open(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:336)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.lambda$openFileWithOptions$0(FileSystem.java:4633)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LambdaUtils.eval(LambdaUtils.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.openFileWithOptions(FileSystem.java:4631)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$FSDataInputStreamBuilder.build(FileSystem.java:4768)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.initialize(LineRecordReader.java:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.<init>(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.TextInputCSVDataSource.readFile(CSVDataSource.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat.$anonfun$buildReader$2(CSVFileFormat.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:353)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: Operation failed: "The specified path does not exist.", 404, HEAD, https://adls.dfs.core.windows.net/raw/file.csv?upn=false&action=getStatus&timeout=90
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsRestOperation.execute(AbfsRestOperation.java:246)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsClient.getPathStatus(AbfsClient.java:648)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.openFileForRead(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:694)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.open(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:263)
    ... 43 more
Command took 0.12 seconds
```

I feel it is some random network error with adls but if it is, how can i see it and fix it??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> If i re-excute the same notebook, it will complete successfully.
> I feel it is some random network error with adls.

Yes, this might be the Network issue as same error has been mentioned on Databricks forum and the author has mentioned the error had resolved by itself. Check [here](https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D53f00001PAXPBCA5/getting-job-aborted-due-to-stage-failure-sparkexception-when-trying-to-download-full-result).

There is no fix available since it is not because of any technical error. But to avoid manual re-run, you can use Azure Data Factory `Notebook` activity and in the **General** tab under **Retry** give a value for the number of times you want to retry if activity fails. Refer below image.

[image]

To deploy the Notebook activity in ADF, refer [Run a Databricks notebook with the Databricks Notebook Activity in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-databricks-notebook)
.

Comment: How can we figure out if it is really a networking issue. Thanks for the suggestion for putting retrying at activity level but suppose if notebook is not running through adf activity then it is really hard to out retry.

Comment: Since you are getting this error only sometimes therefore there must be network issue. You can retry programmatically using try and exception.